# Random Number generator in a range and then print length of the sequence

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I want the application to create a sequence that generates a series of random numbers from 0 to 9 util a 0 is generated and then display the length of the sequence of the numbers. Right now my program only prints 0 or 9 as I don't know the random number generator method.My question is how do I generate a random integer between 0 and 9(inclusive) unit a 0 is generated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sequence {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<Integer>  lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       lista.add(0, 9);



       Random r = new Random();
       System.out.println(lista.get(r.nextInt(lista.size())));
      }
   }
```

Comment: Look up `while` loop.

Comment: ... and your question is?

Comment: My question is how do I generate a random integer between 0 and 9(inclusive) unit a 0 is generated. @Turing85

Comment: @user11833872 show us what you have tried so far. If you have no approach, you may want to look at a basic tutorial, e.g. [this one by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a while-loop:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Sequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int count = 0;
        int num = -1;
        System.out.println("The sequence is:");
        while (num != 0) {
            num = r.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(num + " ");
            count++;
        }
        System.out.printf("%nThe length of the sequence is: %d%n", count);
    }
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
The sequence is:
3 9 3 9 4 0
The length of the sequence is: 6
```

---

Alternatively if you need to store the sequence in a collection:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class Sequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int num = -1;
        while (num != 0) {
            num = r.nextInt(10);
            result.add(num);
        }
        System.out.printf("The sequence is: %s%n", result);
        System.out.printf("The length of the sequence is: %d%n", result.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
Random r = new Random();
int num = r.nextInt(10);

while(num != 0)
{
    nums.add(num);
    num = r.nextInt(10);
}

System.out.println(nums.size());
```

To avoid the List never generating because `num`'s first generated random number *is* 0, consider using an if statement and reassign the value accordingly.

Comment: This only prints the value 2. The program needs to keep generating values between 0 and 9 until it generates 0. It also needs to print the sequence and the length of the sequence @mperic

Comment: OK. Then use a for-each loop to iterate through your List and print the elements sequentially - after the loop is finished. As for the length: just use the size() method.

Comment: How exactly would I do that, sorry I'm a beginner @mperic

Comment: Take a look at Oracle's Java tutorials. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is currently doing the following:

1. Creating a list with 1 element with the value of `9`
2. Your call to Random is evaluating to `Random.nextInt(1)` which will always return 0 as the parameter to `nextInt()` is an exclusive upper bound from 0 to that bound.
3. In short, your implementation will always return, the first item in your list, which is `9`

If you want to get a random number between 0 and 9 then you need to call `Random.nextInt()` with an upper bound of 10, i.e. `Random.nextInt(10)`.

To generate a sequence you need to a while loop that terminates when a 0 is returned from random.

Finally, as you don't seem to care about the sequence generated and just the length you can dispense with the `List`.

So you could try something like the following:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int count = 0;
        while (r.nextInt(10) != 0) {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Sequence Length = " + count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A while loop would be very useful for this. Examine how you say you want numbers to be generated *until* a 0 is generated. When you want something to happen over and over until a condition is met, use a while loop. Here's an example of a while loop that would run until a 0 is generated:

```
ArrayList<Integer>  lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random myRandom = new Random();

int next = myRandom.nextInt(10);
//We use 10 because nextInt() is non-inclusive for the upper bound. It will generate 0 to 9
while(next != 0) {
    lista.add(next);
    next = myRandom.nextInt(10)
}
lista.add(next); //When we get here, a 0 has been generated. Add it to the list.

//To display the length of the list, print out lista.size()
System.out.println(lista.size());
```

I'm assuming you want the sequence to stop when a 0 is generated and still add that 0 to the list. If not, exclude the add(next) after the loop.